# get object's value failed in php

Tags: php

I do print_r($img); and the result is this

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => http://www.thestar.com.my/~/media/Images/TSOL/Photos-Gallery/features/2014/07/02/JamyYangMingjie020714.ashx?crop=1&w=460&h=345&
)

SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => http://www.thestar.com.my/~/media/Images/TSOL/Photos-Gallery/features/2014/07/02/dominiclau020714.ashx?crop=1&w=460&h=345&
)

SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => http://www.thestar.com.my/~/media/Images/TSOL/Photos-Gallery/features/2014/07/02/str2_s8_0207_s8tricovel1.ashx?crop=1&w=460&h=345&
)
```

I want to get only the list of the link. So I do $img[0] it doesn't work, why?

Comment: You need `foreach` loop

Comment: A little more context how that object came to be may help. Probably `(string)$obj` will do it.

Answer (score 2):

You'd use a simple `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($img as $i) {
    echo "<img src='". $i. "' />";
}
```